# Interacting with Firebase (offline and online)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I now this is probably a dumb question, but I'm new to web development and I need to clarify this: to interact with Firebase, my code needs to be in a web server or a CDN, right? I can only test if the connection between Firebase and my files if they are online?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can build and test Firebase apps without putting the files online anywhere.  You can simply create a test.html on your local filesystem and open it in a browser (i.e. as a file://.../test.html url) and Firebase will work 100% fine.

Note that if you want to use [Firebase Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html) (for facebook/twitter/github/email+password auth), the files *do* have to be served by a web server.  You can still do this locally though.  You just have to spin up a local web server.  This can be as easy as "python -mSimpleHTTPServer" if you're on a unix-like OS (linux, OSX, etc.).  Then point your browser at `http://localhost:8000/test.html` or whatever.

You don't need to put the files online until you actually want to deploy your app and have other people use it.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was necessary to put the files in a web server to add/remove data from the Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Your server-side code will need to be on a server to execute, but that server doesn't need to be online. Try a local server like XAMPP or a bitnami stack

Comment: Thanks. But if it is a 100% Firebase-powered apps, where the dynamic content and user data is stored and retrieved from Firebase, I need to have the front end code in a server/cdn to test the connection between my code and Firebase?